# Can I disassemble my code in PLTScheme?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme, racket

Can I see the translated machine instruction of a scheme function like (disassemble) in LISP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `decompile` module providing a function by the same name.  It can be used to decompile a bytecode file into a kind of a human-readable form.  However, this is not a linear assembly-language representation (that is what gets generated dynamically by the JIT), and it's questionable whether it will help you to look at the results.  In any case, [search the documentation](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/search/?q=decompile) for more information.

You can also use the macro stepper to get a rough idea of the kind of complexity that MzScheme actually sees -- just click it, disable all macro hiding, and step through your code until it's completely expanded.  It *will* be hairy.